# Can't display image on JavaFX canvas

Tags: canvas, intellij-idea, javafx

I've just started to dip my toes into the world of JavaFX and come up against a problem when trying to display an image on the canvas. I've searched Google for hours and come up blank.

Here is my code (which I found searching the web):

```
public class Main extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage theStage)
  {
    theStage.setTitle( "Canvas Example" );

    Group root = new Group();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas( 400, 400 );
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    gc.setFill( Color.RED );
    gc.setStroke( Color.BLACK );
    gc.setLineWidth(2);
    Font theFont = Font.font( "Times New Roman", FontWeight.BOLD, 48 );
    gc.setFont( theFont );
    gc.fillText( "Hello, World!", 60, 50 );
    gc.strokeText( "Hello, World!", 60, 50 );

    Image earth = null;
    try{
        earth = new Image("file:/res/earth.png");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("height: "+earth.getHeight()+" width: "+earth.getWidth());
    gc.drawImage( earth, 180, 100 );

    root.getChildren().add( canvas );
    Scene theScene = new Scene( root );
    theStage.setScene( theScene );
    theStage.setResizable(false);
    theStage.show();

  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

It compiles and runs fine, I don't get any exceptions caught, the Hello World text is displayed correctly, but no image. I've tried drawing shapes (like circle and rectangle) and they also work fine as expected, the problem is only when I try to display an image. The getWidth() and getHeight() calls in System.out.println both return 0.0

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2016.3.3 IDE, Java JDK 1.8.0_112 and am completely stuck now. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? Create a `File` object, check the result of `File.exists()`, pass the result of `File.toURI().toString()` to the `Image` constructor.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did what you suggested and sure enough it wasn't finding the file. I had to put an absolute path to get it to work. Do you know if there is a way to use relative paths? I like to keep my resources in a seperate folder from my source code but I can't figure out what to use as a path. I've tried "../res/earth.png" but that didn't work. It doesn't work either if I put the image in the source folder and just refer to it as "earth.png"

Comment: @James_D I did a bit of experimenting and found what the base path is. From there I could see that I needed to add the src folder into the path so my new line for creating the image is `earth = new Image("file:src/res/earth.png");` Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Of course, if the image will be bundled as part of the application, then using a file at all is probably not he best way. There are dozens of questions about this on here. When I am back at the computer I will see if I can dig them out.

Comment: That would be a great help, thanks.